# Scheme flatten a list using only cond, atom?, null?, map, append and foldl/foldr

Tags: list, lambda, functional-programming, scheme, racket

Trying to understand higher order functions in scheme and I'm having a hard time trying to flatten a list using those functions. (flatten '(a (b) (c))) -> (a b c)

```
    (define (flatten s)
       (cond ((null? s) '())
             (foldr (lambda(x) (if (atom? x) (append x)
                          (list x))) s '())))
```

(flatten '(a (b) c)) returns '()

I'm not sure how to use map here and how can I do this using foldl? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the atom from `htdp/docs`, or another?

Comment: thank you, using cond in this way was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `cond` wrong. The contract of the special form is:

```
(cond
  (predicate consequent1 consequent2 ...) ...)
```

The last predicate may be the symbol `else`. Looking at you cond this is how it's interpreted:

```
(cond ((null? s)        ; predicate 
       '())             ; consequent1 (result)
      (foldr            ; predicate (always true since only #f is false) 
       (lambda (x)       ; consequent1 (dead code)
         (if (atom? x)
             (append x)
             (list x))) 
       s                ; consequent2 (dead code)
       '())))           ; consequent3 (result)
```

As you can see it lacks the parentheses around the last term  making `foldr` the predicate. Also even with the parentheses it lacks `else` as predicate and without it the `fold` will only be used to check if it's not `#f` and not as the actual consequent.

Since both terms evalautes to `()` and the last predicate is always true `()` would be the result all the time.

Using `foldl` you'd get the elements in reverse order but it would be faster. With `foldr` you can do it like this:

```
(define (flatten lst)
  (let helper ((lst lst) (acc '()))
    (foldr (lambda (e acc)
             (cond ((null? e) acc)
                   ((pair? e) (helper e acc))
                   (else (cons e acc))))
           acc
           lst)))
```